# Nuxt.js: How to debug server side after nuxt build (logging some information)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, asyncdata

I am using nuxt.js for my frontend app. I currently have a problem with `asyncData` especially the first time it is run (which is on the server).

When building my app (`$ nuxt build` and serving it via [`$ serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)), I currently have no real possibility to console.log some information out from the code that is run on the server. How can I debug that part, before code is run on my client?

Would this be a way:
https://codeburst.io/debugging-nuxt-js-with-visual-studio-code-724920140b8f
So I would launch nuxt manually with `node.js` and try to inspect something there?

Or is there a better way?
The nuxt build properties (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer#options-for-plugin) are just for analyzing the build right? Like package sizes etc, and not for actual code that is run on the server?

I hope I could make clear what I am looking for, if not I am happy to answer further questions.
Any hints are very welcome. Thank you in advance.

cheers

Comment: you could use packages like `morgan`